# How can I set a gdb source mapping for a relative path

Tags: gdb

I have gdb attached to a process and just stopped at a function breakpoint.
Unfortunately I can't see any source code since the mapping seems to be off.

The file it looks for reports as: `../../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_chimera.cpp` and the downloaded source resides in `/home/user/debugging/pyqt5-5.4.2+dfsg/qpy/QtCore`.

No matter what I set as source mapping it won't open the file. What would be the correct syntax for a relative source mapping?

Comment: Have you tried `(gdb) directory /home/user/debugging/pyqt5-5.4.2+dfsg/qpy/QtCore` ?

Comment: This seems to work in gdb. Unfortunately I actually want a graphical debugger so I use QtCreator for that right now. There it seems it does not work to set "directory ..." and I can only set a source mapping. Which I still don't know how.

Comment: I've got the same problem. `(gdb) directory <path pointing to the file>` works but I have to do it again if I step into another file which is annoying. The command "`set substitute-path`" doesn't work for me

Comment: @pterodragon Hi. Did you try GDB 9? Support for substituting relative paths was introduced in [binutils-gdb.git@4fa0265edea0940b865678d93749e224547dd36a](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=commit;h=4fa0265edea0940b865678d93749e224547dd36a) .

Comment: @liki You can probably guess that I didn't. gdb 9 had not been released when I answered! Feel free to update your findings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to run the `directory` gdb command for all the files, I've got a hack that works for me.

Say if your source path is `../../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_chimera.cpp`, and you have moved the source to `/home/user/debugging/pyqt5-5.4.2+dfsg/qpy/QtCore`,

then try creating some dummy directory hierarchy `$ mkdir -p /home/user/debugging/dir_1/dir_2` and run `directory /home/user/debugging/dir_1/dir_2` in gdb.

This way in gdb, `/home/user/debugging/dir_1/dir_2/` concatenated with `../../qpy/QtCore/qpycore_chimera.cpp` is `/home/user/qpy/QtCore/qpycore_chimera.cpp` which is what you want.

In other more complex cases, I'm sure symbolic links will help (for my case as well).

Reference:
https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Source-Path.html

> For example, suppose an executable references the file
>   /usr/src/foo-1.0/lib/foo.c, and our source path is /mnt/cross. The
>   file is first looked up literally; if this fails,
>   /mnt/cross/usr/src/foo-1.0/lib/foo.c is tried; if this fails,
>   /mnt/cross/foo.c is opened; if this fails, an error message is
>   printed. GDB does not look up the parts of the source file name, such
>   as /mnt/cross/src/foo-1.0/lib/foo.c. Likewise, the subdirectories of
>   the source path are not searched: if the source path is /mnt/cross,
>   and the binary refers to foo.c, GDB would not find it under
>   /mnt/cross/usr/src/foo-1.0/lib.
>
> Plain file names, relative file names with leading directories, file
>   names containing dots, etc. are all treated as described above; for
>   instance, if the source path is /mnt/cross, and the source file is
>   recorded as ../lib/foo.c, GDB would first try ../lib/foo.c, then
>   /mnt/cross/../lib/foo.c, and after that—/mnt/cross/foo.c.